# Imprimir linha negativa DPP-450 Datecs EscPos

Tags: java, android, impressora

Estou começando um projeto nessa impressora (DPP-450), e me deparei com um problema que não estou conseguindo resolver:

Preciso imprimir uma linha negativa, fundo preto e escrita em branco.
No manual esta "GS B" como o código para isso, porem só consigo executar os códigos "ESC".
Não sei se existe alguma forma de alternar entre GS/ESC, não pude encontrar nada que me ajudasse.

Answer (score 0):

Olá. 
ESC na verdade corresponde ao char 27. Atualmente uso Delphi então os comandos que usam ESC, são passados assim:

/* Exemplo de negrito */
_prNegritoAtivar : string = #27'E1';
_prNegritoDesativar : string = #27'E0';

Desta forma, para passar o GS, que corresponde ao char 29, faço assim:
/* definindo a largura do código de barras */
_prBarCodeLargura : string = #29'w' + '2'; //entre 2 e 4

no seu caso o GS B, seria: #29'B' 
Sacou ?